# Spark Scala: using an implicit Spark Context in Class Definition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a class in scala that needs a spark context for its methods. Therefore in the class statement I used an implicit spark context and the code compiled fine:

```
class Test (implicit sc: SparkContext) {


}
```

However, when I tried to instantiate the object, I got the following error:

```
val inst: Test = new Test()
error: could not find implicit value for parameter sc: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
```

Is this the wrong way to use a spark context within a class?

Comment: It simply means there is no implicit `SparkContext` in a given scope. Where do you define it?

Comment: When I type in SparkContext or sc into the shell I get org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@ back. Therefore I assume there is one in the global frame. Is there a reason it can't see it? / How do I make it see it?

Comment: Spark context you get in REPL is not `implicit`. Putting aside if it make sense or not you can start with something like this `implicit val isc =  sc`.